# I need to filter through arrays AND objects (using this each function in my filter function below)

Tags: javascript, foreach, filter, each, higher-order-functions

I need my `filter` function to be able to filter through arrays AND objects. How could I use my `each` function in the `filter` function to do that? (I'm pretty sure I'm NOT allowed to modify `each`, either.)

Questions:

1) What does the `each` function produce, for any given array or object?

2) `Each` performs something to each item in an array or object. I'm not sure then how I would use `each` in my `filter` function but also incorporate the `predicate` parameter of my `filter` function to produce my filtered array/object.

3) Note the question mark on bottom. Once we complete my `filter` function, what does that call to `filter` produce?

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4];
var myObject = {
  job: "progammer",
  age: 50
}
var each = function(collection, callback) {
  if (Array.isArray(collection)) {
    for (var i=0; i < collection.length; i++) {
      callback(collection[i]);
    }
  } else {
    for (var key in collection) {
      callback(collection[key]);
    }
  }
};

var filter = function(collection, predicate) {
  var newArr = [];
  for (var i=0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    if (predicate(collection[i])) {
      newArr.push(collection[i]);
    }
  }
  return newArr;
};

filter([1,2,3,4], function(value) {return value > 2;});

// [3,4]

filter(myObject, function(value) {return value.length > 5;});

// ?
```

Comment: `var r=[];function x(a){return a>2;}each(myArray,function(a){x(a)&&r.push(a);});alert(r)`